# how to indent stack trace in python?

Tags: python, exception

I use this code to catch an exception and print a stack trace:

```
def logerr(stmt, e):
    try:
        do_something()
    except:
        print('##EXCEPTION in logging: ')
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback, file=sys.stdout)
```

I get a result like:

```
##EXCEPTION in logging: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amurty\Desktop\dev\eclipse\workspace\hhs\FeedSearch\src\main\main.py", line 18, in main
    log()
TypeError: log() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

But I want the stack trace to have extra indentation, like so:

```
##EXCEPTION in logging: 
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\amurty\Desktop\dev\eclipse\workspace\hhs\FeedSearch\src\main\main.py", line 18, in main
            log()
        TypeError: log() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

How can I achieve this? Will the `pprint` or `textwrap` modules help here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
import traceback

def logerr(stmt, e):
    try:
        ##do something

    except:
        print '##EXCEPTION in logging: '
        for line in traceback.format_exception().splitlines():
            print '        ' + line
```

Comment: awesome. 

i had to tweak the code a bit and use regex (splitlines throws an error - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines') 

this works for me - 

except:
 print getLogStamp() + '--EXCEPTION-- ' + stmt + ' - ' + str(e)
 exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
 for line in traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
  line = regex.sub( '', line.strip())
  print '\t\t' + str(line).rstrip('\n')


warning - this destroys the formatting of trace induced by traceback, like the stepped tabs.

Comment: i am still learning my way around stackoverflow. sorry for all the edits and formatting.